# pyqt5 QMdiSubWIndow hide on close Event

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to redefine the closeEvent on a QMdiSubWindow, so that it executes `hide()`. Currently when I close the subwindow with the x on top and then reopen it, qt shows only a blank subwindow. I think that that is because qt drops all subwidgets once the subwindow is closed/destroyed.

Testing example:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFont(QFont('Sans Serif', 12))
        self.setWindowTitle("Open-light-control")

        sortact = QAction('Sort', self)
        sortact.triggered.connect(lambda: self.mdi.tileSubWindows())

        quitact = QAction('Quit', self)
        quitact.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        quitact.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = self.menubar.addMenu('File')
        self.fileMenu.addAction(quitact)
        self.toolsMenu = self.menubar.addMenu('Tools')
        self.toolsMenu.addAction(sortact)
        self.windowMenu = self.menubar.addMenu('Windows')
        self.mslideract=QAction('Master', self)
        self.mslideract.triggered.connect(self.mslider_window_show)
        self.windowMenu.addAction(self.mslideract)

        self.mdi = QMdiArea()

        self.create_master_fader()
        self.mslider_sub.show()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)

    def create_master_fader(self):
        master_list = []

        self.mslider=QSlider()
        self.mslider.setMinimum(0)
        self.mslider.setMaximum(100)
        self.mslider_max_button=QPushButton("Max")
        self.mslider_min_button=QPushButton("Min")
        self.mslider_resend_button=QPushButton("Resend")
        self.mslider.valueChanged.connect(lambda x: print(x, end="\r"))
        self.mslider_max_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.mslider.setValue(self.mslider.maximum()))
        self.mslider_min_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.mslider.setValue(self.mslider.minimum()))
        width_edit=QLineEdit()
        width_edit.setPlaceholderText(str(self.mslider.size().width()))
        height_edit=QLineEdit()
        height_edit.setPlaceholderText(str(self.mslider.size().height()))
        width_edit.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.mslider.resize(QSize(int(width_edit.text()),self.mslider.size().height())))
        height_edit.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.mslider.resize(QSize(self.mslider.size().width(),int(height_edit.text()))))
        master_list.append([self.mslider, 0, 0])
        master_list.append([self.mslider_max_button, 0, 1])
        master_list.append([self.mslider_min_button, 1, 1])
        master_list.append([self.mslider_resend_button, 0, 3])
        master_list.append([width_edit, 0, 2])
        master_list.append([height_edit, 1, 2])

        self.create_sub_area("mslider", "Master", master_list)

    def mslider_window_show(self):
        self.mslider_sub.show()

    def create_sub_area(self, name, title, wid_list, width=None):
        exec("self.{0:s}_layout = QGridLayout()".format(name))
        for wid in wid_list:
            exec("self.{0:s}_layout.addWidget(wid[0],wid[1],wid[2])".format(name))
        if width:
            exec("self.col_count=self.{0:s}_layout.columnCount()".format(name))
            for col in range(self.col_count):
                exec("self.{0:s}_layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(col,{1:d})".format(name,width))
        exec("""self.{0:s}_widget = QWidget()
self.{0:s}_widget.setLayout(self.{0:s}_layout)
self.{0:s}_sub = QMdiSubWindow()
self.{0:s}_sub.setWidget(self.{0:s}_widget)
self.{0:s}_sub.setWindowTitle('{1:s}')
self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.{0:s}_sub)
self.{0:s}_sub.hide()""".format(name,title))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There could be different solutions to your question (and reasons for which what you describe is happening), and that depends on how you implemented your Mdi area and its sub window creation/management.

Comment: Could you explain your question better, for example, why do you want to override closeEvent? Also because you point out that the QMdiSubWindow is destroyed